# How do I create a 2D array of struct using dynamic allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, 2d

I have a struct which has 2 parameters and I create a 1D pointer array of the type of the struct and allocate memory for it. This is send into a function with values to add to it. The code it below.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[LENGTH];
    double  use;
} Task;



Task *ctask;
  task = malloc(8 * sizeof(*task));

insert (Task task[], name, use){
    //does something
    task[i].name =  name;
    task[i].use = use;
}
```

what I want to know is how do I create a 2D array of pointer of type struct(of size 8*25). And send it to the function insert().

Is this below correct:

```
Task **ctask;
  task = malloc(8 * sizeof(*task));

for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
    task[i] = malloc(25 * sizeof(*task));
}
```

When im sending it to the insert function does it need to be changed or can I just send in:

```
insert(task[i], name, use);
```

appreciate any feedback
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `C`, you can use either an array (length 8) of pointers to arrays (length 25) or an array (length 8 * 25) to represent a 2D array. Please see [The C Programming Language by K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) for details.

For the first method,

```
Task **taskArray = (Task **) malloc(8 * sizeof(Task *));
int n;
for (n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
    taskArray[n] = (Task *) malloc(25 * sizeof(Task));
}
// access the row i, column j Task struct in the array
// taskArray[i][j]
// you will need its address/pointer to pass to insert function
// &taskArray[i][j] or taskArray[i] + j
```

For the second method,

```
taskArray = (Task *) malloc(8 * 25 * sizeof(Task));
// access the row i, column j Task struct in the array
// taskArray[i * 8 + j]
```

About calling the `Insert` function

```
Insert (Task task[], char *name1, double use) {
    int i = getindex(name1); 
    task[i].name = name1; 
}
```

From your code, the `task` would be the name/head pointer of the struct array, you access its i-th struct using `task[i]`.

For 1D array, you just past the name or head pointer to it.

For 2D array using first method, `taskArray` is an array of 8 (in depth) 1D arrays of 25 struct (in width). You can call `Insert` for each of this 1D array, just passing in their head pointer, `taskArray[i]` for the i-th.

For 2D array using second method, it's the similar idea, except that you have to convert the index of 1D array to simulate as 2D array. The head pointer for each of the 8 1D arrays is `taskArray[i * 8]` for the i-th.

Comment: Hi neo,how do i call the insert function for this 2D array (for both tge examples you have given) just ti send the i'th row. Because the insert row calls another junction to calculate its index j. For the 1d array tge finction is as below.

Comment: Insert ( Task task [], char *name1, double use)
      { 
      int i= getindex (name1);
       task [i].name= name1;
      }

Comment: Hi,

the for a 1D array the insert function was as below:

    Insert ( Task task[], char *name1, double use) { 
    int i= getindex (name1); 
    task[i].name= name1; 
    } 

In calling the function how do I change the insert function to take the 1 array of 50 elements.

Comment: As updated in the answer, hope it solve your problem. My suggestion is try to master the concepts of multiple dimension array in `C` before moving on the pointers or dynamic allocated memory, it will help you with a smooth experience in programming.

Comment: sure,thanks I will do that, when I do the for loop for 8(as mentioned above), and do a printf I don't get the data in the 2D array but when I do the for loop to 25, and do a printf like taskArray [r][c], I get the data in the 2D array. what is the reason for this? I do not understand why this is happening. could you explain please

Comment: It's exactly the concept behind C arrays (pointers as reference, dereferencing pointers, and array index). I'll leave you to The C Programming Language by K&R, because I can't explain them any better than the authors do.